# SFSafariViewController - Interacting with the parent app from a web-page

Tags: ios, native, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm trying to research a way to load a web view controller into an iOS app, such that the web page can communicate data back up to the parent.

Is this possible with `SFSafariViewController`? Is there some mechanism like post-messaging, which will let me send data back up to the native app?

Note: it's pretty important that I use SFSafariViewController, since I also need the web view to persist/share cookies with Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `SFSafariViewControllers` are not sandboxed, like all other implementations of `UIWebView`, it means that they have access to private information, such as cookies.

As a safety measure, the `SFSafariViewController` is then sandboxed from the rest of the app. The one way to communicate between it and your app is through a [custom URL scheme](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html).

The drawback of this is that you need to be in control of the web-service, and implement an API for this purpose (however you shouldn't really be able to access cookies otherwise).

You can follow [this project](https://github.com/mackuba/SafariAutoLoginTest) to get you started.

Hope this helps,

Liam

Comment: The `SFSafariViewController` is sandboxed for a reason. Using URL schemes to continuously send information back to the app is rather bad practice. If you really need to do that you should consider using the `WKWebView` instead which is built for that use case. The doc clearly says:
`If your app customizes, interacts with, or controls the display of web content, use the WKWebView class.`

Comment: is there a way with WKWebView to add an entitlement to share auth with a domain which you own?