# Safari View Controller - send data back to app

Tags: ios, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

I implemented Safari View Controller in iOS app, but is there a way to send some data from javascript of opened site to main iOS app.
I am opening my web app in the Safari VC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFSafariViewController - Interacting with the parent app from a web-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164505/sfsafariviewcontroller-interacting-with-the-parent-app-from-a-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. from Apple Guideline and i quote.

> The view controller includes Safari features such as Reader, AutoFill,
>   Fraudulent Website Detection, and content blocking. It shares cookies
>   and other website data with Safari. The user's activity and
>   interaction with SFSafariViewController are not visible to your app,
>   which cannot access AutoFill data, browsing history, or website data.
>   You do not need to secure data between your app and Safari

Comment: It doesn't say nor confirm that VC can't send data to the main app.
What about Custom app uri, knowing we are still in the same app?

Comment: i just answered your question.What you are asking now is modification. :)